# What is difference between object creation inside class but out side method and object creation inside method

Tags: java

What os difference between below two ways. If i use way 1 what will happen and if i use way 2 then what will happen:
 Way 1:

```
class LoginPageTest extends TestBase
    {
    **LoginPage login=new LoginPage();**
    @Test
    public void Login_validCredentials()
    {
    }
}


Way 2:
public class LoginPageTest extends TestBase
    {
    LoginPage login;

    @Test
    public void Login_validCredentials()
    {
        **login=new LoginPage();**

    }}
```

Comment: Do you know what a constructor is? The first initialization is actually part of the constructor of your class. So it's called every time a LoginPageTest object is created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is an *instance member initialization*. It happens when a new `LoginPageTest` object is created (effectively, the initialization is relocated to the beginning of each constructor).

Your second one leaves the instance member with its default value (`null`) until/unless you call `Login_validCredentials`. If you never call that, it will remain `null`. If you call it repeatedly, it will replace the instance member each time you call it.